# BlackBerry - How to attach and get particular Field id in KeywordFilterField

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I have set up a KeywordFilterField (Thanks to Signare - http://rincethomas.blogspot.in/2012/04/search-field-in-bb.html) and everything works, however, I would like to know how to make them do something or open a new screen when pressed / clicked. Someone (also Signare) suggested I attach a field id to the field in focus and then use that value to open new screen when clicked, but I do not know how to implement this.

Below is my code:

```
public class IndexScreen extends MainScreen {

    KeywordFilterField _keywordFilterField;
    CountryList _countryList;

    public IndexScreen() {
        _countryList = new CountryList();
        _countryList.addElement(new Country("Zimbabwe"));
        _countryList.addElement(new Country("Argentina"));
        _countryList.addElement(new Country("Brazil"));
        _countryList.addElement(new Country("Canada"));
        _countryList.addElement(new Country("Chile"));
        _countryList.addElement(new Country("China"));
        _countryList.addElement(new Country("Germany"));

        _keywordFilterField = new KeywordFilterField();
        _keywordFilterField.setLabel("");
        _keywordFilterField.setSourceList(_countryList, _countryList);

        setTitle(_keywordFilterField.getKeywordField());
        add(_keywordFilterField);
        // this.addMenuItem(addElementItem);

        // add(this);
    }

    void addElementToList(Country country) {
        _countryList.addElement(country);
        _keywordFilterField.updateList();
    }

    private final MenuItem addElementItem = new MenuItem("Add country", 0, 0) {
        public void run() {
            _keywordFilterField.setKeyword("");

            String[] selections = { "Add", "Cancel" };
            Dialog addDialog = new Dialog("Add Country", selections, null, 0,
                    null);
            EditField inputField = new EditField("Country: ", "");
            addDialog.add(inputField);

            if (addDialog.doModal() == 0) {
                addElementToList(new Country(inputField.getText()));
            }
        }
    };
}

class SearchFieldDemoScreen extends MainScreen {
    public SearchFieldDemoScreen() {
    };
}

class CountryList extends SortedReadableList implements KeywordProvider {
    public CountryList() {
        super(new CountryListComparator());
    }

    void addElement(Object element) {
        doAdd(element);
    }

    public String[] getKeywords(Object element) {
        if (element instanceof Country) {
            return StringUtilities.stringToWords(element.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    final static class CountryListComparator implements Comparator {
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            if (o1 == null || o2 == null)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "Cannot compare null countries");

            return o1.toString().compareTo(o2.toString());
        }
    }

}

class Country {
    private String _countryName;

    public Country(String countryName) {
        _countryName = countryName;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return _countryName;
    }

    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {

        Field f = getFieldWithFocus();
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    private Field getFieldWithFocus() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will display the clicked country name.

```
public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen
{
    KeywordFilterField _keywordFilterField;  
    CountryList _countryList;
public MyScreen(){
 _countryList = new CountryList();
        _countryList.addElement(new Country("Zimbabwe"));
        _countryList.addElement(new Country("Argentina"));
        _countryList.addElement(new Country("Brazil"));
        _countryList.addElement(new Country("Canada"));
        _countryList.addElement(new Country("Chile"));
        _countryList.addElement(new Country("China"));
        _countryList.addElement(new Country("Germany"));

        _keywordFilterField = new KeywordFilterField(){
             protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
                 int index = getSelectedIndex();

                 String str = (((Country) getElementAt(index)).toString());
                 Dialog.alert(str);

                return true;
             }
        };
        _keywordFilterField.setLabel("");
        _keywordFilterField.setSourceList(_countryList, _countryList);
        add(_keywordFilterField);

}

}

class CountryList extends SortedReadableList implements KeywordProvider
{
    public CountryList()
    {
        super(new CountryListComparator());      
    }

    void addElement(Object element)
    {
        doAdd(element);      
    }

    public String[] getKeywords(Object element)
    {
        if(element instanceof Country)
        {
            return StringUtilities.stringToWords(element.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    final static class CountryListComparator implements Comparator
    {
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2)
        {
            if (o1 == null || o2 == null)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot compare null countries");

            return o1.toString().compareTo(o2.toString());
        }
    }

}

class Country
{
    private String _countryName;

    public Country(String countryName)
    {
        _countryName = countryName;      
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return _countryName;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you update your blog post similarly to correct the code that is there?